# Circuit to light up an LED with a potentiometer

Tags: led, resistors, potentiometer

I have a 10k potentiometer and an LED. I want a circuit to light up the LED only when the potentiometer is at one specific value. It can ramp up in brightness to that value, and then ramp down past it. It doesn't need to be very precise or narrow, just clearly brightest at one point that is not either extreme of the potentiometer. That's it. I could always make a window comparator, but I have to make several dozen of these so I would prefer not to use comparators and logic gates. Is there a simple way I could arrange a couple resistors and diodes to get the job done? Thanks!

Comment: You asked this question already. But your demands are unrealistic. You want a certain behaviour but do not want to use the component(s) which makes such behaviour possible. Electronics may seem like "magic" but we still need parts to make that magic happen.

Comment: downvote for repeating the question ... please edit your first question instead, then delete this question

Comment: Barev!  If you want a function, say why / how ,but offer no restriction , but add scope and cost. Quick answer, No...with a 555 IC , yes

Comment: @Oldfart Actually, there is (or used to be anyway) a potentiometer that had a fixed center-tap along with the usual "wiper." It would be relatively easy with one of those. Haven't seen one in some decades. But of course, the OP is talking that the specific potentiometer that they actually have. But just taking a series pair of resistors of the same value and tying their midpoint to the wiper and the opposite ends to the associated ends of the potentiometer will achieve a variable resistance that goes from \$5000\:\Omega\$ to \$6666\:\Omega\$ and then back again.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it can be done. But you'll need several BJTs. Let's assume that you have a \$5\:\text{V}\$ power rail (you mentioned that figure in your prior question.) The following circuit can be used:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQsZyA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You will need to adjust \$R_1\$ and perhaps \$R_2\$ to get the peak brightness you want, while at the same time also getting the "not ON" result you want, as well. Those two resistors are key to working it out to what you need.

The basic idea is that there is about a 60% to 100% variation in the resistance of the combination \$R_4\$. \$R_5\$, and \$R_6\$ in the *variable resistance* box. This will vary from about \$2.13\:\text{k}\Omega\$ to about \$3.51\:\text{k}\Omega\$ (at center) and then back to the lower resistance, again, at the other end of travel.

We want the Darlington configuration of \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$ to turn completely off when the *variable resistance* box is at \$2.13\:\text{k}\Omega\$ but also to turn completely on when the *variable resistance* box is at \$3.51\:\text{k}\Omega\$.

To achieve this, we need a current source that is relatively independent of the voltage rail (in this case, we assume about \$5\:\text{V}\$.) \$Q_3\$, \$R_2\$, and \$R_3\$ create this current source which is here set to about \$450\:\mu\text{A}\$.

That's about all there is. I'd probably leave \$R_1\$ alone and play with \$R_2\$ to get the desired result. If you can't get it just right with \$R_2\$ changes, then I'd consider either lowering or raising \$R_1\$ by a factor of 2 (roughly) and then go back and adjust \$R_2\$ to get the desired result. It's not terribly complicated and you should be able to get where you want to get with this. But do notice that you need two NPN and one PNP and a few other resistors to get there.

It's not a really well-managed circuit. Ambient temperature, for example, will have an impact. An increasing ambient temperature affects the \$V_\text{BE}\$ of all three BJTs by reducing their\$V_\text{BE}\$. This means the sum of the two \$V_\text{BE}\$ drops in the Darlington arrangement shrinks. If that change becomes large enough, it might mean that the LED doesn't fully turn off. But in compensation of this, \$Q_3\$'s \$V_\text{BE}\$ (also changed) will yield a smaller constant current, throwing the excess current overboard by way of its collector into ground, thereby lowing the base voltage at the Darlington arrangement, which might be sufficient to allow the circuit to continue as desired.

But this is for an LED. So I'm not going to make rocket science out of this and I believe it is sufficient to get about where you want to be.

Answer (score 4):

If we connect two diodes with different forward voltages VF in parallel and supply this network by a current source, the current will flow through the diode with the lower VF. This trick is used in the circuit below to autocommutate LEDs with different VF, e.g. green (2.5 V) and red (1.5 V), with the purpose to indicate when the input voltage is below, equal and above the threshold.

[image: LED voltage indicator]

The resistors R1 and R2 form a voltage divider. The ratio R2/(R1 + R2) determines (roughly) the voltage threshold; the sum R1 + R2 sets the current through LEDs. A base resistor can be inserted to decrease the sensitivity.

When the input voltage (at the potentiometer slider) is equal to the threshold voltage, both transistors are turned off. The string of two red LEDs in series (D1 and D2) with total VF = 3 V is connected in parallel to the green LED D3 with VF = 2.5 V. The current flows through +VCC -> R1 -> D3 -> R2 -> ground; so D3 is lit and D1,D2 are extinguished.

If the input voltage is below the threshold voltage, T2 is turned on thus shunting D2 and connecting D1 in parallel to D3. The current flows through +VCC -> R1 -> D1 -> T2 -> R2 -> ground; so D1 is lit and D2,D3 are extinguished.

If the input voltage is above the threshold voltage, T1 is turned on thus shunting D1 and connecting D2 in parallel to D3. Now the current flows through +VCC -> R1 -> T1 -> D2 -> R2 -> ground; so D2 is lit and D1,D3 are extinguished.

The *voltage drop across* and *current through* the D1-D3 network are relatively constant; only the current is steered between diodes.

See also a [paper about this circuit solution](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/279016).

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fordI4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A crude but simple solution.*

How it works:

- R2 limits the LED current. Decrease the value to get more current.
- R1 biases Q1 on.
- R3 steals the bias from Q1 turning it off. At either end of the pot all the bias current is diverted from Q1 and it turns off. In the centre there is enough to turn Q1 on.

[image]

*Figure 2. The results of a simulation as R3 is adjusted from min to max.*

Comment: Another example of Don Lancaster's "elegant simplicity"... The constant threshold is the only drawback... but you can use a non-linear potentiometer to move it. Now you just have to remove the transistor and  connect the LED directly to the potentiometer to obtain the perfect simplicity...